# Why do I get "foreign key mismatch" error?

Tags: sql, sqlite

I don't understand why I get the error, could you explain please?

```
sqlite> create table a (id text, val text);
sqlite> create table b (bid text, ref text, foreign key(ref) references a(text));
sqlite> insert into a values("1", "one");
sqlite> insert into b values("1", "one");
Error: foreign key mismatch
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you've got a number of things slightly strange here. I would write this as follows:

```
create table a (id text, val text, primary key(id));
create table b (bid text, ref text, foreign key (ref) references a(id));
insert into a values("1", "one");
insert into b values("one", "1");
```

Create a primary key on A and then reference it from B; not that I reference the field name not the datatype in the foreign key.

The mismatch is because you're trying to "match" `one` and `1`. You should have switched round the values in the B insert.

[SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!7/8fb05/1)

Answer (score 2):

you don't have a field called `text` in table a..

You probably meant to do:

```
sqlite> create table a (id text, val text primary key(id));
sqlite> create table b (bid text, ref text, foreign key(ref) references a(val));
sqlite> insert into a values("1", "one");
sqlite> insert into b values("1", "one");
```

Answer (score 1):

You might be getting this error because you have not declared primary key in `table a`.Also in references you must mention primary key column name not datatype.
e.g.

```
sqlite> create table a (id text PRIMARY KEY, val text);
                               // ^---Declared Primary key
sqlite> create table b (bid text, ref text, foreign key(ref) references a(text));
                                          refer primary key column--------^
```